# Is there an offline command-line dictionary?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, dictionary

Is there any command line offline dictionary? I know that there are some like 
**StarDict** and **Artha** but how about one in the command line?

Also, I tried `dict` but it is an online dictionary.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**[sdcv](http://sdcv.sourceforge.net/)** is the console version of **Stardict**.

**1. Install the dictionary**

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install sdcv
```

**2. Download dictionary files**

Download the dictionary files according to your requirements from the following sources.

- List of [dictd-www.dict.org Dictionaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20140917131745/http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/dict.org/) (archived):

  - [The Collaborative International Dictionary of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_International_Dictionary_of_English) (GPL, 35MB, 174222 words) (download [tarball from archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140917131745/http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/dict.org/stardict-dictd_www.dict.org_gcide-2.4.2.tar.bz2))
- https://web.archive.org/web/20140428004049/http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/misc/
- [Free On-Line Dictionary of Computing](http://foldoc.org/)
- [Jargon File](http://catb.org/jargon/html/online-preface.html) - A comprehensive compendium of hacker slang illuminating many aspects of hackish tradition, folklore, and humor
- [GNU Linux English-English Dictionary](http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/misc/stardict-xfardic-gnu-linux-2.4.2.tar.bz2)

**3. Install downloaded dictionaries**

Make the directory where `sdcv` looks for the dictionary:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/stardict/dic/
```

The next command depends on whether the downloaded file is a `.gz` file or a `.bz2` file.

If it is a `.bz2` file:

```
sudo tar -xvjf downloaded.tar.bz2 -C /usr/share/stardict/dic
```

If it is a `.gz` file:

```
sudo tar -xvzf downlaoded.tar.gz -C /usr/share/stardict/dic
```

**4. Done!**

To search for a word use:

```
sdcv word
```

[image]

Comment: Marked and also +1 for the installation guide

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks for the informational answer!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: You probably can install the dictionary from packages, for example something like `stardict-dic-en`. If you install the GUI version of Stardic (e.g. `stardict`) you probrably will get the english dictionary automatically.

Comment: Some other links to download, [bigdict](http://download.huzheng.org/bigdict/), [google-stardict](https://sites.google.com/site/gtonguedict/home/stardict-dictionaries)

Comment: How to resolve this: `mkdir: /usr/share/stardict/dic/: Operation not permitted` ?

Answer (score 41):

## Easy offline `dictd` installation

#### Rationale

**The `dict` command can easily be used with offline dictionaries.** It suffices to install the `dictd` daemon with its dependencies alongside a local, offline dictionary. 
This turns out to be a much easier procedure than installing `sdcv` as suggested elsewhere on this page.

#### Installation

Below is shown how to install `dictd` along with the `dict-gcide` comprehensive English dictionary. There are [many more dictionairies](https://web.archive.org/web/20180816203245/http://xmodulo.com/how-to-look-up-dictionary-via-command-line-on-linux.html) available from the standard repositories.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dict dictd dict-gcide
```

#### Usage

```
$ dict word

 3 definitions found

    From The Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48 [gcide]:

      Word \Word\, n. [AS. word; akin to OFries. & OS. word, D. woord,
         G. wort, Icel. or[eth], Sw. & Dan. ord, Goth. wa['u]rd,
         OPruss. wirds, Lith. vardas a name, L. verbum a word; or
         perhaps to Gr. "rh`twr an orator. Cf. {Verb}.]
         [1913 Webster]
         1. The spoken sign of a conception or an idea; an articulate
            or vocal sound, or a combination of articulate and vocal
            sounds, uttered by the human voice, and by custom
            expressing an idea or ideas; a single component part of
            human speech or language; a constituent part of a
            sentence; a term; a vocable. "A glutton of words." --Piers
            Plowman.
            [1913 Webster]

                  You cram these words into mine ears, against
                  The stomach of my sense.              --Shak.
            [1913 Webster]

                  Amongst men who confound their ideas with words,
                  there must be endless disputes.       --Locke.
            [1913 Webster]

         2. Hence, the written or printed character, or combination of
            characters, expressing such a term; as, the words on a
            page.
            [1913 Webster]

         3. pl. Talk; discourse; speech; language.
            [1913 Webster]
```

Comment: The webpage linked here that points to more dictionaries seems to be broken. Here's an archived copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20180816203245/http://xmodulo.com/how-to-look-up-dictionary-via-command-line-on-linux.html

Answer (score 14):

You probably also have `aspell` installed, which has the advantage of giving suggestions for misspelled words. You can call `aspell` directly on your text file with:

```
aspell check text.txt
```

or use it on a single word:

```
echo wrd | aspell -a
```

Comment: if not yet installed: `sudo apt-get install aspell aspell-es` (for program + spanish dictionary)

Comment: to specify the Spanish dictionary, you can use `-l es`

Answer (score 7):

If you're just looking to see if a word is spelled correctly or exists, you can use grep to look through the word list files in /usr/share/dict/, which are provided by the appropriate [wordlist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/wamerican) packages.  An example to see if "emu" is a valid word:

```
grep -i "^emu$" /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

That doesn't have any definitions, however.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for definitions...

Comment: Don't you need single quotes or `\$`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use free dictionary with `dict` command:

- First install via `sudo apt-get install dictd`
- Find out which language dict you want to use `sudo apt-cache search "dict-freedict"`
- After find these names install them (for ex.) `sudo apt-get install dict-freedict-eng-tur`
- Check which languages are installed `dict -D`
- Use like: `dict "word"`
- Specific usage: `dict -d fd-eng-tur "word"`

Answer (score 3):

How about downloading dictionary text file from the sites for example [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sujithps/Dictionary/master/Oxford%20English%20Dictionary.txt) (**warning**: 4.5 MB), and then finding the text with command like `grep "word" dictionary.txt`

Or also by using **VIM** editor to search for the word with its command eg. `/Word`. And
by pressing <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> for next or previous occurance of the pattern is more fun with finding meaning of the word.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Princeton University WordNet application. I did not want to deal with Tcl/Tk so prepared a make file that allows you to run WN as a command line application. You do have to compile it, but I provide instructions to help somewhat. I personally find it automatic to popup a terminal on my Linux computer and type "wn unknown-word -over" anytime I want the definition for unknown-word. The nice thing about WordNet is that you get synonyms, antonyms and other linguistic nuances if you want it. Here is my github download link:

[Dalton Bentley github link for WordNet command version](https://github.com/AncientZygote/WNtight)

Incidentally, I edited all of the Princeton linguistic help files into a rational pdf which those interested in the more advanced capabilities will appreciate.