# Offline commandline Thesaurus?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, application-development, shared-library, dictionary

[Online command-line thesaurus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079574/online-command-line-thesaurus)

This here has answers for an Online thesaurus. I need an offline thesaurus for the commandline. If there is none, is there a library available in the repos containing something like a database for synonymns and antonymns that I can use to make an application with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
pdftotext 'MyThesaurus.pdf' - | grep -A2 -B2 dog | less
```

that is 2 lines before and 2 lines after

It would work best if the thesaurus had a format like
each adjective at https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/each

dog adjective

the you could search for

dog adjective or dog noun or dog verb etc

write a script that does all that and takes a word as input like

sh mythesaurus.sh dog

Answer (score 0):

Looks like answers for [Is there an offline command-line dictionary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191125/is-there-an-offline-command-line-dictionary) might help you.

In short:

- [sdcv](http://sdcv.sourceforge.net/) is the console version of Stardict.
- You can use free dictionary with `dict` command (dictd)